# Changing the target page of pagination in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have the following pagination code in php :

```
    $targetpage = "demodesk.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 10;                                //how many items to show per page
$page = @$_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;     //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */

$sql = "SELECT * FROM desktop where Place in($commalist) LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;          //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">&lt&lt previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">&lt&lt previous</span>";    

    //pages 
if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
    elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
            if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next &gt&gt</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next &gt&gt</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
 ?>
```

This pagination code displays the results on the same page as the file name. I want a way to change the targetpage to another page's `<div>` . Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Stop suppressing your variables/functions (`@`).

Answer (score 0):

*You should change your targetpage `$targetpage = "demodesk.php";` to your new page `$targetpage = "yournewpage.php#idOfDiv";`
Then on the other page you should give your div an id and replace the `idOfDiv` in the URL above with the ID of your div*

---

But because you're using your `$targetpath` further in your code to place any parameters behind it, you should do something else.

You can make a variabele. For example `$idOfDiv = myDiv;` and place after every link where you use `$targetpath` `#$idOfDiv`

So you get

```
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev#$idOfDiv\">&lt&lt previous</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter#$idOfDiv\">$counter</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter#$idOfDiv\">$counter</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1#$idOfDiv\">$lpm1</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage#$idOfDiv\">$lastpage</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1#$idOfDiv\">1</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2#$idOfDiv\">2</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter#$idOfDiv\">$counter</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1#$idOfDiv\">$lpm1</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage#$idOfDiv\">$lastpage</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1#$idOfDiv\">1</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2#$idOfDiv\">2</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter#$idOfDiv\">$counter</a>
<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next#$idOfDiv\">next &gt&gt</a>
```

You can optimize your code, but that's something for you to do..
See more about anchor tags [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

Comment: I did the same thing but on clicking the second or third or so on page's link, nothing is happening.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you did. You should always put it behind in the link. So `$pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter#yourIdOfDiv\">$counter</a>";` Check answer for more

Comment: Do I have to put #yourIdOfDiv behind each and every link used in pagination?

Answer (score 0):

First, place default $page value before setting it with $_GET[page] value.

```
$page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['page'])) $page = intval($_GET['page']);
```

After that validate $page - should be: more or equal than 1, less or equal than $maxpage.

After that make that all into a function:

```
function pagination($target) {
}
```

And pass the parameter like

```
$str = pagination('demodesk.php');
```

That should do it.